# When is the Kullback–Leibler divergence continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory, entropy

For two probability measures $P,Q$, if $P\ll Q$, then the Kullback–Leibler divergence (or the relative entropy) is defined as:
$$D_{KL}(P||Q)=\int\log\bigg(\frac{dP}{dQ}\bigg)dP.$$
It is well known that for any two measures $P$ and $Q$, $D_{KL}$ is lower semicontinuous in $P,Q$. My question is: what are the conditions on $P,Q$ that make $D_{KL}$ continuous in the weak topology?

Comment: Notice that $Q$ should be fixed and the space of probabilities of interest are those for which $P\lll Q$. In fact, $D_{KL}(P)=\infty$ for any probability $P$ that his not absolutely continuous w.r.t $Q$. So in reality, at least this is how is see your problem, once the $Q$ is fixed, you are interested in the $P$s for which the map $P\mapsto D_{KL}(P|Q)$ is continuous (the weak topology in the domain)

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes this would answer my question

Comment: I suspect $D_{KL}(\cdot|Q)$ has no continuity point since for any $P\lll Q$ and weak neighborhood $V$ of $P$ there are measures that are not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q$. For example, suppose $x_0\in X$ is such tha $Q(\{x_0\})=0$. Then $\mu_n=(1-\frac1n)P+\frac1n \delta_{x_0}$, $n$ large enough, is one such measure.